# PhpStorm array is not closing on line start

Tags: php, phpstorm, editor

I edited the code styles settings some time ago but I *"broke"* something about the short array syntax which I can't find how to fix.

For example, let's say I call a function and pass an array:

```php
my_func([]);
```

If I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to write array elements on multiple lines, I get this (which I find awful):

```php
my_func([

        ]);
```

---

What should I change in the settings in order to get my array like this:

```php
my_func([

]);
```

*I'm on PhpStorm 2019.3 on Ubuntu.*

**EDIT**: here is the export of the settings:

```xml
<code_scheme name="Default" version="173">
  <PHPCodeStyleSettings>
    <option name="ALIGN_PHPDOC_PARAM_NAMES" value="true" />
    <option name="ALIGN_PHPDOC_COMMENTS" value="true" />
    <option name="ALIGN_ASSIGNMENTS" value="true" />
    <option name="ALIGN_INLINE_COMMENTS" value="true" />
    <option name="CONCAT_SPACES" value="false" />
    <option name="COMMA_AFTER_LAST_ARRAY_ELEMENT" value="true" />
    <option name="PHPDOC_BLANK_LINE_BEFORE_TAGS" value="true" />
    <option name="PHPDOC_BLANK_LINES_AROUND_PARAMETERS" value="true" />
    <option name="LOWER_CASE_BOOLEAN_CONST" value="true" />
    <option name="LOWER_CASE_NULL_CONST" value="true" />
    <option name="KEEP_RPAREN_AND_LBRACE_ON_ONE_LINE" value="true" />
    <option name="ALIGN_CLASS_CONSTANTS" value="true" />
    <option name="FORCE_SHORT_DECLARATION_ARRAY_STYLE" value="true" />
    <option name="NAMESPACE_BRACE_STYLE" value="2" />
    <option name="PLACE_PARENS_FOR_CONSTRUCTOR" value="1" />
  </PHPCodeStyleSettings>
  <codeStyleSettings language="JSON">
    <indentOptions>
      <option name="INDENT_SIZE" value="4" />
    </indentOptions>
  </codeStyleSettings>
  <codeStyleSettings language="PHP">
    <option name="LINE_COMMENT_AT_FIRST_COLUMN" value="false" />
    <option name="LINE_COMMENT_ADD_SPACE" value="true" />
    <option name="ALIGN_MULTILINE_CHAINED_METHODS" value="true" />
    <option name="ALIGN_MULTILINE_PARAMETERS_IN_CALLS" value="true" />
    <option name="ALIGN_MULTILINE_FOR" value="false" />
    <option name="ALIGN_MULTILINE_TERNARY_OPERATION" value="true" />
    <option name="SPACE_AFTER_TYPE_CAST" value="true" />
    <option name="CALL_PARAMETERS_LPAREN_ON_NEXT_LINE" value="true" />
    <option name="CALL_PARAMETERS_RPAREN_ON_NEXT_LINE" value="true" />
    <option name="METHOD_PARAMETERS_WRAP" value="1" />
    <option name="METHOD_PARAMETERS_LPAREN_ON_NEXT_LINE" value="true" />
    <option name="METHOD_PARAMETERS_RPAREN_ON_NEXT_LINE" value="true" />
    <option name="METHOD_CALL_CHAIN_WRAP" value="1" />
    <option name="TERNARY_OPERATION_WRAP" value="1" />
    <option name="TERNARY_OPERATION_SIGNS_ON_NEXT_LINE" value="true" />
    <option name="ARRAY_INITIALIZER_WRAP" value="5" />
    <option name="ARRAY_INITIALIZER_LBRACE_ON_NEXT_LINE" value="true" />
    <option name="ARRAY_INITIALIZER_RBRACE_ON_NEXT_LINE" value="true" />
  </codeStyleSettings>
  <codeStyleSettings language="SCSS">
    <indentOptions>
      <option name="INDENT_SIZE" value="4" />
    </indentOptions>
  </codeStyleSettings>
  <codeStyleSettings language="Shell Script">
    <indentOptions>
      <option name="INDENT_SIZE" value="4" />
    </indentOptions>
  </codeStyleSettings>
  <codeStyleSettings language="yaml">
    <indentOptions>
      <option name="INDENT_SIZE" value="4" />
    </indentOptions>
  </codeStyleSettings>
</code_scheme>
```

Comment: seems working:- https://3v4l.org/fsLAe

Comment: @AnantSingh---AlivetoDie yes it works, but this is all about the code style, I don't want it to indent the array closing `]`.

Comment: This a question for the [support / forum](https://www.jetbrains.com/support/). Has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: @MarkusZeller I always found answers to PHPStorm settings issues on SO, but I agree.

Comment: Check stuff at `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Code Style | PHP | Wrapping and Braces` tab -- could be some option under `Function/constructor call arguments` or `Array initializer` nodes...

Comment: @LazyOne yes I tried to change stuff in both of theses sections but I can't find how to fix this. I guess I'll have to reset all the code style settings I applied or manually fix it every time...

Comment: Show those settings of yours. Even better -- export it to XML file (has to be XML, not JSON) and share it.

Comment: @LazyOne did not know about that ! I edited my question with the export. Thank you

Comment: I do not know what you have tried .. but if I untick all 3 check boxes under `Function/constructor call arguments` it places `])` at the beginning of the line. `Align when multiline` option in particular. Other 2 are controlling empty lines after `(` and before `)`. see https://postimg.cc/Z0zgHFWB

Comment: @LazyOne Finally !! Thank you. I tried various settings, I got confused at some point about what I tried or not. Just unticking `Align when multiple` solved it. You can post it as an answer if you want :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check stuff at `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Code Style | PHP | Wrapping and Braces` tab -- should be one of the options under `Function/constructor call arguments` or `Array initializer nodes`...

Based on your exported Code Style file, that would be `Function/constructor call arguments | Align when multiline` option. Other two are controlling empty lines after `(` and before `)`.

[image]