# PhpStorm PSR-12 Code style adds extra 21 spaces to array

Tags: php, arrays, formatting, phpstorm

After selecting PSR12 code style in PhpStorm I get extra 21 spaces in array column:

```
$columns->addHeaders([
    'Number',
                         'Number in words',
                         'Number in words length'
                     ]);
```

Instead of:

```
$columns->addHeaders([
    'Number',
    'Number in words',
    'Number in words length'
]);
```

**Is there any way to configure PhpStorm to auto-format code like in second example, but leaving all other PSR-12 configs?**

P.S. I understand, that using PSR-12 I should start array in next line (example below), but sometimes I still need to use first method of formatting:

```
$columns->addHeaders(
    [
        'Number',
        'Number in words',
        'Number in words length'
    ]
);
```

Comment: Have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61044335/783119

Comment: For what it's worth, this is not a PSR-12 setting. Remember that PhpStorm code format settings are extremely fine-grained, much more than most coding standards.